# Route to internal IP while on lan, otherwise, external IP

Tags: networking, proxy, routing

I have a couple services available to the external network. I'm using Apache virtual hosts to reverse proxy all my stuffs.

```
192.168.1.134 > site.domain.com
```

I want to redirect `site.domain.com` to its internal IP, `192.168.1.134` when I am on the LAN.

This is helpful for things like Plex. If I have a big download running, rather than streaming the content over the net and back to myself, if I connect to the internal IP I don't need to worry about my bandwidth being utilized for the download rather than the stream.

Comment: The term is [hair-pinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning).  Most home grade routers do it by default anymore.  Commercial grade you likely need a rule or route.

Comment: I have the nighthawk r6000 i think is the model.

Comment: Ive seen it mentioned to modify the hosts file, but i dont recall where i saw that, or what they said to add. Running ddwrt on my router though if theres a way to do it within that software

Comment: I use an r7000 with stock firmware, it hairpins by default, no setup required.

Comment: Well this may actually already be happening behind the scenes. is there a way to check? It SEEMS to run better when i access it over the internal ip, but that could just be me seeing what im expecting to see.

Comment: what does traceroute tell you?